# Validation of (Measurement of units)

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp

I have a text box that allow users to key in their desired unit, 
and i would have to validate if this unit does exist.

Example 1: KM/H (Correct) 
Example 2: KA/H (Wrong)

I know that emails address can be validated using codes like C#, JavaScript, Etc. 
Is there any ways that I can validate (Units of measurement) through any codes, web service etc ? using Javascript, JSON?

P.s I am working on a JSP page :)

Comment: you can validate using Javascript, not JSON, it's a data format.

Comment: Hi Asgs, Thanks for your reply.

Do you have any ref links for me? so that i can follow them step by step

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is fully capable of validation (though it should not be used to validate at the expense of server-side validation, for security reasons). You can validate either by simple string checking (as below, which seems suitable to your case) or, for more complex, pattern-based validation, regular expressions.

**Assumed HTML:**

```
<form id='unit_form'>
    <input type='text' name='unit' />
    <input type='submit' value='go' />
</form>
```

Then, when the button is clicked (using jQuery...)

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var valid_units = ['KM/H', 'KM']; //etc...
    $('#unit_form').on('submit', function() {
        var unit = $('input[name=unit]').val();
        if ($.inArray(unit, valid_units) == -1) {
            alert('bad unit!');
            return false; //cancel form submission
        }
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc9zA/1/)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question.<br/>

I tried working with your codes but it didn't work as expected. 
I didint get any alerts when I keyed in a radom values, but the URL shows the unit values that i have keyed in.

If possible, can i know what does this line of code means? 
  if ($.inArray(unit, valid_units) == -1) {

Comment: See the JS Fiddle - it validates the inputted unit when the form is submitted, i.e. you get the alert then if you've entered an invalid unit. Is that not what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

GNU publishes a nice little program called [Units](http://www.gnu.org/software/units/).  It neatly does what you want.

Comment: Hi thb, Thanks for providing the link, 
But the link doesn't really provide me with I need, instead of validating the data, it shows the conversion of conversion units.